# In Django's template engine, how do I display a datetime object in a meaningful way?

Tags: python, django, templates, datetime

```
{{ p.date }}
```

is displayed as:

```
Date: 2010-10-29 21:56:39.226000
```

How do I make changes to how that's displayed?

Answer (score 5):

Using date filter, for eg : `{{ study.created_date|date:"d/m/Y"}}`

Answer (score 1):

With the [`date`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) filter.

Comment: there's also a related `timesince` on the same doc page